# apcupsd not starting, but I can get a full response from apcaccess status

Tags: debian

Debian Buster
apcupsd.conf is defaults plus:
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE
DEVICE

This is the preferred setting to leave those blank. If I make anything else but blank, I get a

apcupsd  /defunct

and a system message of communication lost

If I run apcaccess status I get a full response

HOSTNAME : SERVER2
VERSION  : 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian
UPSNAME  : SERVER2
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2020-05-25 12:57:00 -0700
MODEL    : Back-UPS BR1000G
STATUS   : ONLINE
LINEV    : 123.0 Volts
LOADPCT  : 5.0 Percent
BCHARGE  : 100.0 Percent
TIMELEFT : 154.3 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 20 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
SENSE    : Medium
LOTRANS  : 88.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 147.0 Volts
ALARMDEL : 30 Seconds
BATTV    : 27.0 Volts
LASTXFER : Automatic or explicit self test
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 Seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 Seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
SELFTEST : NO
STATFLAG : 0x05000008
SERIALNO : 3B1147X25837
BATTDATE : 2011-11-18
NOMINV   : 120 Volts
NOMBATTV : 24.0 Volts
NOMPOWER : 600 Watts
FIRMWARE : 868.L2 .D USB FW:L2
END APC  : 2020-05-25 13:28:59 -0700

## /sbin/apcupsd start

gets me nothing in messages

Any suggestions?

EDIT: ran apctest, and found 
apctest FATAL ERROR in apctest.c at line 313
Unable to create UPS lock file.

/var/lock is hard linked to /run/lock

I cleared out the LCK.. files in there.
Looked for pids
I tried a start again, it did create a LCK.. file, but still exited the test the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run `apcaccess` and get the output like shown, it means `apcupsd` is running.

You can check with `sudo systemctl status apcupsd`.

You cannot perform `apctest` when the service is started. Stop it first with `sudo systemctl stop apcupsd`, then try `apctest`.